# What's the meaning of the speaker's remark?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> P1: Winter coat crew, whatchu wearin? Need a new winter coat. my trusty navy-issue peacoat is old as hell.
>
> P2: I'm just having seconds when the mashed potaters get passed around. I think that should do it.

What is the responder saying? What's the meaning of his remark?

Comment: It means that he is having a second helping of [mashed potatoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashed_potatoes) as they get passed around the table. He thinks that should fill him up.

Comment: The comments sound like they don't have anything to do with one another. Are you sure the second one is a reply to the first?

Comment: What sort of English is this? Could you please give the source of that dialogue?

Comment: It's from a forum thread. Although only members could view the thread. The remark was made by a user in response to the thread starter *P1*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> P1: Winter coat crew, whatchu wearin? Need a new winter coat. my trusty navy-issue peacoat is old as hell.

P1: O those who have insight into coats for winter, tell me what you wear. I need a new winter coat. I have a heavy coat that I acquired from the Naval forces, but it is quite old.

> P2: I'm just having seconds when the mashed potaters get passed around. I think that should do it.

P2: For myself, I am going to eat more helpings of mashed potatoes. That should keep me warm in the winter due to the increased adipose tissue.

Comment: I agree with your P1 reading, and the P2 interpretation looks quite likely, except there's a slight chance it might mean: “I just take whatever hand-me-down coat I'm given, it usually works ok.”

Comment: I think that's a very, very small chance.